# angular-handsontable display decimal value

Tags: angular, decimal, display, handsontable

I am using angular-handsontable in my application. I need to display a decimal value (22.45) without rounding to the nearest. When I use,

```
columns: ({ type: string; numericFormat: { pattern: string; }; } | {})[];
this.data = [     
      ['99.259999999999']
      ];

 this.columns = [
{type: 'numeric', numericFormat: { pattern: '0.00%' }}
];
```

My value is displayed as 99, instead of 99.25. How can we achieve this using handsontable

Answer (score 1):

Try by iterating you data array before using  and apply `toFixed` or `Math.round` function for every value.

**Cutting decimals**

```
this.data.forEach(item => {
    item = item.toFixed(2);
});
```

**Rounding decimals**

```
 this.data.forEach(item => {
        item = Math.round(item * 100) / 100;
    });
```

Comment: where should I use toFixed? To the value or at the format level

Comment: In you case it could be something like this  `this.data[0].toFixed(2)` even if you have more values you can give format before use it. By iterating the array.

Comment: can please elaborate more or create a fiddle. Didn't get where to add

Comment: Ready I Modified my post.

Comment: Now it is rounding after the decimal to 99.26 instead of 99.25

Comment: It doest round just cut the decimals, let me put other funtion to round up

Comment: great! if the rounding function is configurable(in the sense, to how many places would it round to) that would be good. we may have some requirement like this.

Comment: ready try by using my example  `Math.round(item * 100) / 100`

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: No. Still getting rounded value after decimal. I used const x  = Math.round(Number('12458.3599') * 100) / 100; and its rounded to 12458.36

Comment: and what do you need? round up, round down, or just crop

Comment: I don't want any trim or round. I want to see the value 'AS IS'(ORIGINAL VALUE) WITHOUT modification

Comment: ok, well `toFixed` just to be clear this function do not do any round just crop the decimals  if you have 12.259 you will get the first two decimals 12.25